# CSS code not working only when website is live

Tags: html, css, hosting

I'm working on a website and have been trying to make some changes to the `contact.css` CSS of the [contact page]. I edited the CSS file and the changes that I was seeing offline weren't reflected online.

Specifically, I changed the `background-color:blue`, which worked offline as seen here:

I then replaced that file on my hostgator server and I double checked that it was replaced correctly by re-downloading the CSS file from my cPanel.

`background-color:blue` was definitely still part of the code.

But when I view the website online. `background-color:blue`, is mysteriously not part of the CSS file anymore.

I assumed this must be a caching issue so I cleared the cache on both firefox and chrome, but still no luck. I then tried opening the website on Opera which I haven't done before so there should be no cache. No luck.

The online page still isn't updating to blue, and looks like this:

Comment: reupload css and remove cache then hard refresh :)

Comment: I've already reuploaded and opened it in a totally new browser

Comment: delete browsers history and then hard refresh  alt+f5

Comment: I've cleared cache on firefox and chrome

Comment: Is it working on your end? Can you confirm it's a caching issue?

Comment: no still not work

Comment: when i visited your page is like above screenshot

Comment: this is working in my machine

Comment: @jsRook which screenshot? The blue one or the white one?

Comment: on visiting the contact page.  it is blue one

Comment: i add screen shot working fine

Comment: @jsRook Yes you must be right. It is a caching issue. But I just cleared cache and hard refreshed and it still isn't showing as blue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, seems to be something with the caché. Tried to see my web on another web viewer and the background-color was there. In my case i was using Firefox, and then tried to see the web with edge

Answer (score -1):

Check the css file path. In server the path might vary.

Comment: Good idea, but no luck path is fine. It's definitely a caching issue.

Comment: Yup, it might be the server cache.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve it in chrome, but not firefox, by going into the developer tools and disabling the cache from there under the "network" tab. No other method of clearing cache seems to work.

Comment: Nope nevermind this didn't work. I'm having the same issue again