# Having trouble clearing cache to refresh webpage

Tags: html, css, caching, hosting

This may sound like a very basic question but I feel like I've tried everything.

This a follow-up to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55114208/css-code-not-working-only-when-website-is-live/55114504?noredirect=1#comment96971026_55114504) I made earlier, where I resolved the issue, only for it to come back again.

To summarize, I was making some change to the `contact.css` file on the [contact page](http://matthewbellanalytics.com/pages/contact.html) of my website when I noticed the changes were working offline but didn't appear online. I narrowed this issue down to a caching issue with the above post (others could see the changes but I couldn't).

In the above example I couldn't get my website to show up as `background-color:blue` - eventually it worked and I thought I'd fixed it... So I go to change the color back to normal and boom, it stops refreshing the changes again.

So I think it's some sort of caching issue but for the life of me I can't get my cache to clear properly so that I can refresh and see the changes.

Here are the things I have tried already:

- Clearing cache (many times) on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera
- Hard refresh on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera
- Disabling cache through dev tools on Chrome and Firefox (this worked initially then stopped working when I re-updated the website)
- Checked multiple times that the CSS file uploaded correctly and the file path was correct. This was confirmed because the correct changes were seen by other people.
- Flushed my DNS
- Changed from my ISPs DNS to google's 8.8.8.8 + 8.8.4.4

I'm using HostGator to host my website, I'm wondering at this point whether it's something to do with them? I really just have no idea at this point.

Here's what I see online:
[image]

Here's what I should be seeing and what I do see on the offline version of my website:
[image]

Comment: Not being snippy... Have you tried searching "Hostgator Cache Problem" in Google?

Comment: Yeah but couldn't find anything I hadn't tried already. There was an article on how to clear caches and one on flushing DNS. It may have nothing to do with hostgator, that was just a total guess. I think I'm just a noob and I'm missing something - I doubt a platform as large as them would have such a glaring flaw in their service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you said "I'd really like to get to the bottom of the underlying issue" so I figured I'd write an answer to provide a few options (and if anyone wants me to add others, please feel free to add a comment). Overall though, determining your root cause is likely much harder than just solving your overall problem, but let's start with possible causes that I can think of off my head:

- Multiple CDN servers taking a while to update so some are returning the old data (your current session) and some are returning new (incognito)
- Server session caching so when you reload the page within one http context session you get back the same content (I've seen this in product search queries for example)

The solution to this is relatively simple though, it's called cache busting. Basically, every time you update your source code just add a unique key in either the query string, file name or something to make the url unique. For example, for your css you can link `https://path/to.css?v2.0.1` and just keep increasing the version number as you go. If you use webpack for your build outputs, they have a [content hash variable](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) that you can use as a token in the file names.

As for the CDNs possibly caching things out of date... the content hash solution will solve that problem as it's an entirely different file name so the CDN will go get it from the root if it doesn't have it in it's cache. I'm unsure of the url version query parameter will do the same, maybe someone else could shed some light on that.

Comment: I should note, I didn't go deep into all cache busting techniques because there are answers on stack about that already that do a far better job than I ever would about explaining it so hopefully knowing the term will help!

Comment: This is fantastic. I've never heard of cache busting but that makes a lot of sense. I think that you are probably right about the servers taking a while to update as well. Thank you for a very complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Incognito in Chrome?

Comment: Nice. I can't believe that worked. Thank you. I've upvoted you but I'd really like to get to the bottom of the underlying issue so I'm going to keep waiting for other answers.

Comment: Hmm this solution didn't work on mobile for me though

Comment: Chrome mobile also have incognito.

Comment: Seems like there is an issue in how you designed your website. Please check the resources and versions of js plugins in your application. Maybe its time to make some clean up.

Comment: There are no JS plugins aside from google analytics. It's almost purely HTML + CSS

Comment: maybe it is your way of structuring the html and assigning css class that causes the issue. Make sure the html start and end tag matches and placed in correct order. Also the css, avoid using obsolete css syntax, try creating a separate file for your css so that you can easily maintain it.